# You got that available

Tags: sentence-meaning

**Reporter**: Hi. Today we're here with Captain Paul Lesley of the fire department and he's going to give us a few tips about fire prevention around a stove.

**Captain**: When you're cooking with oil, so you want to make sure you got a lid that fits your pot securely. **You got that available**. The reason for that is that if the pot catches fire,
you could slide that slowly over the pot and extinguish the fire.

---

What does " **You got that available**" mean?

Answer (score 3):

I presume that this is transcribed from audio or video, and the Fire Department Captain is speaking. His speech is quite informal and he tends to omit words that he doesn't think are important.

> When you're cooking with oil, [so] you want to make sure *that* you *have* got a lid that fits your pot securely, *and that* you *have* got **that** available. The reason for that is that if the pot catches fire, you could slide **that** slowly over the pot and extinguish the fire.

I have added the words *in italics* and highlighted the places where he uses **that** to refer to the pot lid.

I hope that you can now see that "you got that available" means "make sure that you have the pot lid available".

Comment: Yeah, I think he's probably correcting himself to be more specific - you don't just need to own a lid for the pot, you need to have it nearby, ready to use if a fire breaks out. He's repeating the second part of the previous sentence, changing part of it.